# How to find specific element for the this code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to find specific element for this below code?

`id`, `class`, `name` is not there and tried with `x path` which is also not.

```
<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Package Detail" data-index="0" data-field="PackageDetail.Namee" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
 <span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
 <a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=PackageDetail.Namee-asc">Package Detail</a</th>


<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Category" data-index="1" data-field="Category" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
 <span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
 <a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=Category-asc">Category</a></th>


<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="Name" data-index="2" data-field="Name" data-role="columnsorter">
 <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
 <span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
 <a class="k-link" href="/Valiadationrule/GetData?ValiadationruleGrid-sort=Name-asc">Name</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Too bad I cant comment yet. Here is the question what do you wanna find. The links?

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Category")); // for example. Unless the site is in several different languages, you might wanna use a cssSelector or.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.k-link:nth-child(2)"));  //This is for package detail
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.k-link:nth-child(4)")); //This is for category
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.k-link:nth-child(6)")); //This is for name button.
```

These are the elements I currently I am able to click one with the code snippet you gave me.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your update but what i am looking is some what different ,I have an filter ,Once its clicked Filter menu will display in that i will type the package name to display only the specific package.when i try to see the element using fire bug by selecting the filter <span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a> the code is highlighted and but the class has been used multiple times so little confused how to code in java to select the filter menu to display

Comment: Heia. As you are using Firefox, you might wanna try the firefox default element inspector. It has an option to copy an Unique Selector which should do the trick.